# Subscribing to a ObservableCollection via reflection

Tags: reflection, .net-3.5

How can I subscribe to a `ObservableCollection<??>` without knowing the element type of the collection? Is there a way to do this without too many 'magic strings'?

This is a question for the .NET version 3.5. I think 4.0 would make my life [much](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) easier, right?

```
Type type = collection.GetType();
if(type.IsGenericType 
   && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
{
    // I cannot cast the collection here
    ObservableCollection<object> x = collection;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ObservableCollection* implements *INotifyCollectionChanged* interface, so it can be very simple:

```
((INotifyCollectionChanged) collection).CollectionChanged += 
        collection_CollectionChanged;
```

Comment: I should have been able to come up with this on my own!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to subscribe to CollectionChanged with a little bit of reflection:

```
void AddCollectionChangedHandler(ICollection collection, NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler)
{
    Type type = collection.GetType();
    if(type.IsGenericType
       && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObservableCollection<>))
    {
        EventInfo collectionChanged = type.GetEvent("CollectionChanged");
        collectionChanged.AddEventHandler(collection, handler);
    }
}
```

It uses one 'magic string' but it subscribes the given handler to the event.